# How can I translate the <Any> option for a grouped exposed filter in Views?

Tags: i18n-l10n, views

I have an exposed filter in Views that uses the *Grouped filters* option to present choices to users.  By default, an **`<Any>`** option is provided.  My site is multilingual, so I want to translate this:

[image: exposed filter]

I am using the i18n suite of modules as well as i18nviews.  I first searched using the *Translate interface* screen at `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` and I translated **`<Any>`**; however, when viewing the page, **`<Any>`** is still displayed, not the translated value.

There appears to be no option to customize the **`<Any>`** text within the Views UI.

I am able to translate the (user-defined) grouped filter options using i18n and i18nviews through the *Translate Interface* screen.

What do I need to do to translate **`<Any>`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a bug in Views at the moment, so I wrote a [patch](https://drupal.org/node/2134547).

Once you apply the patch (or once the patch is committed to Views), you can translate  as part of the built-in interface through the *Translate Interface* screen.